# Ubuntu start up screen broken

Tags: boot

I set up dual boot on my extra pc last night.

**First** installed windows 7 and that  went just fine.

Downloaded Ubuntu and then did the MD5SUM and did not get a correct return that were listed on the site.

I forgot to do that before I burnt the image to a disc, so I booted from the disc anyway to do the intergrity check and no errors were found.

I then installed and everything seems fine except when it's booting, the purple screen is broken. should I try to redownload and re install?

Answer (score 1):

When you see the Grub menu, hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key.

> This special mode of Grub allows you to temporarily modify Ubuntu's boot parameters.

Add to the end of the line:

```
acpi=off
```

---

If this worked, do the following once Ubuntu is loaded to make the change permanent:

```
gksu nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line that looks like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

So that it now reads:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
```

Save the file, then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference in the md5sum that you see is telling you that you have a download that was corrupted in some way.  There's a difference in the iso file that may, and probably has, caused you problems.

The Integrity check only tests to see if the disk is 100% readable, it does *not* mean that the iso was not corrupted during download.

You will need to get the iso again.  If you have a problem downloading reliably then you should use one of the torrent downloads since torrents have built-in block testing and recovery in case of corruption.  I've had one or two corrupted iso files from normal downloads over the years, but not one since I started using torrents for downloading them.